# Make chrome extension available in all websites

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension. Want it to be always enabled.

I tried to do it in the following way:

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function(){
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
    conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({pageUrl: { urlContains: '*' },})],
    actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
  }]);
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work correctly.
How to get this done?

Comment: `urlContains` accepts only plain text. You can use `:` as it's present in all URLs. However it's not clear why you use this API in such case - you can simply declare a standard browser_action in manifest.json

Answer (score 8):

If you just want your icon to be visible all the time, the standard way to do that is through the `browser_action` field in your `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": {
        "32": "images/icon32.png" // Chrome supports various icon sizes (in pixels)
      },
      "default_title": "Title", // The title that shows up when a user hovers on your icon
      "default_popup": "popup.html" // The URL of your popup page
  }
}
```

Presumably, it should be the same as whatever `page_action` entry you already have.

For more details, see: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction